# Link tag padding all over the screen

Tags: html, css

I got HTML code that simply creates menu and logo image, now the image is working fine though I've added link (`<a href="index.html">...picture...</a>`) to the logo image that will move the "user" back to index page.

The problem is the logo image `<a>` tag is padding all over the screen (width only, the height is fine) and it show me pointer cursor all around the `.header` class background.

How can I fix it without removing the link?

**Ways I've tried:**

```
.linklogo{
    width: 400px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nwvzs2r7/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `.linkLogo` to `display: inline-block` so it recognizes the height/width of its child `div`:

```
.linklogo{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nwvzs2r7/1/)

Comment: You got it. Glad to help.